# Error 1064 from trying to forward engineer an ERD

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, erd

I'm still learning SQL at the moment and i keep getting this error when i try to forward engineer my tables. Could really use some assistance on figuring out what's causing the error.

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
>
> CONSTRAINT `fk_Player_Team1`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
>       REFERENC' at line 11

SQL Code:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sts18`.`Player` (
      `player_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `team_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `player_lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `player_fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `player_age` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `player_phone` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `player_email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      `player_notes` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`),
      INDEX `fk_Player_Team1_idx` (`team_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Player_Team1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
        REFERENCES `sts18`.`Team` (`team_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 17 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running? As far as I know, attribute `VISIBLE` was introduced in 8.0

Comment: I'm running 8.0.17. How does visibility work in SQL? I'm pretty new to the language.

Comment: Your code works fine [in this MySQL 8.0.18 db fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b7fa0b3752346a042cd65e82cb37e34).

Comment: What happens if you remove keyword `VISIBLE` from your code (that's the default anyway): do you still get the error?

Comment: Wow, that fixed it completely! Any idea why the tables would have that attribute in the first place?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html). I tend to doubt that you are running MySQL 8.0, since it works in the db fiddle (unless some changes were done between version 8.0.17 and 8.0.18).